# Error in colyseus server inside Java Script

Tags: javascript, express, colyseus

I've written code and it's giving me errors.

```
const colyseus = require("colyseus");
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const port = process.env.port || 3000;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const demoServer = new colyseus.Server({
  server: http.createServer(app),
});

demoServer.listen(port);
```

Getting this error which i've provided below:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: 'pingInterval', 'pingMaxRetries', 'server', and 'verifyClient' Server options will be permanently moved to WebSocketTransport on v0.15    
new Server({
      transport: new WebSocketTransport({
        pingInterval: ...,
        pingMaxRetries: ...,
        server: ...,
        verifyClient: ...
      })
    })
```

Comment: it's actually a warning, not errors, and it's telling you exactly what is going to happen

Comment: So, how to resolve this

Comment: doesn't the warning tell you what to do?

Comment: Actually, I've added this code to run the server but it's didn't run can you suggest something.

Comment: did you include it exactly? don't do that - how about you show what you tried in the question - you say it didn't run, what did it do instead?

Comment: Thanks, for that now answer this error is resolved. Thanks for your valuable time and reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "@colyseus/core";
import { WebSocketTransport } from "@colyseus/ws-transport"

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app); // create the http server manually

const gameServer = new Server({
  transport: new WebSocketTransport({
      server // provide the custom server for `WebSocketTransport`
  })
});
```